# Activities pane on Manage Case page

Tags: civicase, activities, sort-order

Does anyone know how to make the Case activities in the activities pane display in **ascending** order by default (earliest first)? At the moment, they appear in descending chronological order (latest first). I'm happy to do a bit of tweaking, if someone could point me in the right direction for finding the relevant file(s) to edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the answer*. The file is civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityTab.tpl, and the display settings for the activity tab are in line 77. Change 'desc' to 'asc'.

In the same line, you can also change the default number of lines displayed (change to one of the preset values 25, 50 or 100).

The details of this answer refer to CiviCRM 4.7.3, Joomla version. Not sure if there may be a difference with other platforms.