# Manage Case ─ display activities in chronological order

Tags: civicase, activities

Joomla 3.9.2
CiviCRM 5.12.0

On the Manage Case page, the activities are now displayed in a clever order (overdue first, then the rest in newest-to-oldest order). I can imagine that this makes sense in some situations, but it doesn't in ours, so I need to tweak the code to have a simple ASCENDING order (oldest last). Previously, I had tweaked civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityTab.tpl to replace
class="nestedActivitySelector crm-ajax-table" data-page-length="10" with
class="nestedActivitySelector crm-ajax-table" data-page-length="50" data-order='[[0,"asc"]]'>
 (see also [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10190/activities-pane-on-manage-case-page)), but this tweak no longer has any effect.

Can some kind developer please point to the part of the code which I need to change? Thank you.

Comment: That tweak still seems to work when I apply it. Some other customization conflicting maybe?

Comment: Thanks very much for checking it. Turns out the problem is I'm a numpty. I was tweaking one installation and looking for the effect in a different one. What a noob.

Comment: Ha ha. I guess you can answer the question and mark it answered, just so it doesn't sit unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it turns out the problem was one of numptitude, not a problem with CiviCRM. In fact the tweak works fine, as Demerit kindly confirmed.